# How to install cocoa pods in terminal?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I read cocoa pods documents and many times try to installed but always fail to installed because in starting steps i found one error so i can't install gems first. can anyone give me steps one by one? how to install or demo.

this is one link which i try.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/12139/introduction-to-cocoapods

**OUTPUT in terminal**

**$ sudo gem install cocoapods**
or i try
**$ sudo gem install cocoapods -V**

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just try this before install cocoa pods

$ sudo gem update —system

then use this commond

$ sudo gem install cocoapods

Hope this will solved your issue.

Comment: $ sudo gem update —system->Nothing to update but error occurred

Comment: it seems that ruby is not installed in your system. just check this macintos/Library/Ruby folder exists in your system.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue with your Ruby installation. You're running 1.8.7(mentioned in comment) which has been retired: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/06/30/we-retire-1-8-7/

Update Ruby(see https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) and then run:

```
sudo gem update --system
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: Updete for ruby 2.1.2 was successful, but when i fire the command "$ sudo gem install cocoapods" then the same error occurred

Comment: @LaljiKanjariya did you remember to run `sudo gem update --system` before running `sudo gem install cocoapods`?

Comment: yes i have run the command, my MAC OS X is 10.8.5 so is the problem caused by my OS X ?

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry. How did you update ruby? Using homebrew?

Comment: I have updated rudy 2.1.2 in Terminal from this link https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/